# Not being able to access a variable from my Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller

I have a controller which goes like this

```
@Controller
public class EditCategoriesController {
    @Autowired
    ICruxPanelClientService iCruxPanelClientService;

    @Autowired
    private TmplUrlFetchService tmplUrlFetchService;

    private static String cruxClientUrl;
    private ApiEndPoints apiEndPoints;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            apiEndPoints = tmplUrlFetchService.getUrlFromConfigFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        cruxClientUrl = apiEndPoints.getCruxClientUrl();

    }


    private static int cat_id;
    private static String cat_catkey;
    private static int cat_index_order;
    private static ArrayList<ServiceMaster> serviceMaster;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editCategories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editCategories(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map, Map<String, Integer> map1) {
        iCruxPanelClientService.setCruxWebServiceBaseURL(cruxClientUrl);
        GetCategoriesListResponse response = iCruxPanelClientService.getCategories(new GetCategoriesListRequest());
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModel = response.getCategoryModels();
        ArrayList<String> categoryname = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryModel.size(); i++) {
            CategoryModel m = categoryModel.get(i);
            categoryname.add(m.getName());
        }
        map.put("category", categoryname);
        return "editCategories/editCategories";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/printCategoryDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Category printCategoryDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String res = request.getParameter("categor");
        System.out.println(res);
        iCruxPanelClientService.setCruxWebServiceBaseURL(cruxClientUrl);
        GetCategoriesListResponse response = iCruxPanelClientService.getCategories(new GetCategoriesListRequest());
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModel = response.getCategoryModels();
        CategoryModel m = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryModel.size(); i++) {
            m = categoryModel.get(i);
            String name = m.getName();
            if (name.equals(res)) {
                break;
            }


        }
        Category c = new Category();
        cat_id = m.getId();
        cat_catkey = m.getKey();
        cat_index_order = m.getIndexOrder();
        c.setCatkey(m.getKey());
        c.setColor(m.getColor());
        c.setIcon(m.getIcon());
        c.setIcon_white(m.getIconWhite());
        c.setId(m.getId());
        c.setName(m.getName());
    /*GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdRequest request1 = new GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdRequest();    
    request1.setId(cat_id);
    GetServiceDataIdByCategoryIdResponse response1 = iCruxPanelClientService.getServiceDataIdByCategoryId(request1);*/
    /*ArrayList<ServiceMaster> service = new ArrayList<ServiceMaster>();
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        ServiceMaster serv = new ServiceMaster();
        serv.setCcNumber("12344444");
        serv.setCta("123");
        serv.setIcon("sdgf");
        serv.setId(1);
        serv.setKey("dsgdfg");
        serv.setName("name");
        serv.setOrderSuccessMessage("fgjdoi");
        serviceMaster.add(serv);

    }*/

        c.setPosmNumber(cat_id);
        return c;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/printPosmDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ArrayList<Posm> printPosmDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ArrayList<Posm> messages = new ArrayList<Posm>();
        String catid = request.getParameter("catId");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n" + catid + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        Posm posm = new Posm();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            posm.setName("serviceMaster.get(i).getName()");
            posm.setMessage("serviceMaster.get(i).getOrderSuccessMessage()");
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\nsakjhdkashdkhasd" + catid + "\n\n\n\n\n");
            messages.add(posm);
        }

        System.out.println(serviceMaster.size());
        return messages;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(HttpServletRequest request) {
        iCruxPanelClientService.setCruxWebServiceBaseURL(cruxClientUrl);
        UpdateCategoryRequest updateCategoryRequest = new UpdateCategoryRequest();
        CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
        categoryModel.setColor(request.getParameter("color"));
        categoryModel.setIcon(request.getParameter("icon"));
        categoryModel.setIconWhite(request.getParameter("iconWhite"));
        categoryModel.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        categoryModel.setId(cat_id);
        categoryModel.setKey(cat_catkey);
        categoryModel.setIndexOrder(cat_index_order);
        updateCategoryRequest.setCategory(categoryModel);

        System.out.println(request.getParameter("posmi1"));
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("posmi2"));
        System.out.println(categoryModel.getColor() + "   " + categoryModel.getId() + "   " + categoryModel.getKey() + "    " + categoryModel.getIndexOrder());
        iCruxPanelClientService.updateCategory(updateCategoryRequest);

        return "redirect:editCategories";
    }
}
```

In the API `/printPosmDetails` i am trying and accessing the Arraylist then it throws and error but i am able to access other global variables like cat_id and similar . Why is this happening ?

Comment: can you post what is the error your are getting?

Comment: @subbu royal . I am calling the API through an AJAX call . It just goes on to the error function of the AJAX call and doesn't print an error in the log

Comment: `inspect ` and check on `networks` you came to know what is going on. or you have to `debug`